# How does Earth rotate on its axis, clockwise or anti-clockwise?

Tags: angular-momentum, orbital-motion, earth, conventions

How does Earth rotate on its axis, clockwise or anti-clockwise? How does Earth orbit around the Sun, clockwise or anti-clockwise? How do Earth's satellites orbit around the Earth, clockwise or anti-clockwise?

Comment: define "sense of rotation". You can't just throw words together and expect people to understand what you mean.

Comment: By the parenthesized "i.e." I suppose by "sense" the OP means "direction".

Comment: When it's 9AM in California, it's noon in New York.

Comment: Depends on whether you are [Aussie](http://www.odtmaps.com/detail.asp?product_id=McA-23x35)

Comment: Why didn't Qmechanic fix the "How do"s?  That's the question I want an answer to...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is essentially a meaningless question unless you specify a system with respect to which you define both clockwise and anti-clockwise. If you don't do this, then there really is no way to answer: when seen from above the North pole, the Earth rotates in a counter-clockwise direction, whereas when seen from above the South pole, it rotates in a clockwise sense. The orbital motion of Earth about the Sun has those same characteristics.

Similarly, satellites suffer from the same ambiguity. However, you *can* relate their motion to that of the Earth, and there you use the terms [prograde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrograde_and_prograde_motion), for objects that orbit in the same direction as the natural rotation of Earth, and retrograde, for objects that orbit in the opposite sense. *Most* artificial satellites are placed into prograde orbits, though [a few](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_satellites_in_retrograde_orbit) are placed in retrograde orbits (at the cost of much higher fuel requirements on the launch) for various reasons.

The same is true for natural satellites: most known objects around planets orbit in prograde orbits; this is the natural orbit for satellites that were born with the planet, and it's also much easier to get captured into. However, again, there's some [irregular moons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irregular_moon) out there with retrograde orbits, usually captured from some weirdo solar orbit at some point in the past.